# Java For loop not looping. For loop conditional error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a problem within the section of code I am required to write for an assignment. I am coding in Java. Everything in my code works perfectly except for (what I think to be) the loop condition.

This code is supposed to get 2 values, a and b. a refers to how many times the loop should be performed. b refers to a number. So if a = 5 and b = 5, the output should be:

```
5 x 1 = 5  
5 x 2 = 10  
5 x 3 = 15  
5 x 4 = 20  
5 x 5 = 25
```

I will include my code and if anyone can help me fix my assignment or tell me what I am overlooking, that would be a huge help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxMultiples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Maximum Number: ");
        int maxnum = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Multiplier: ");
        int mult = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Displaying multiples of " + mult + ":");

        int current = 1;
        int result = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter == maxnum; counter++);
        {
            result = mult * current;
            System.out.println(mult + " x " + current + " = " + result);
            current++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two errors :

1. Remove the `;`, since it ends the for loop (meaning you have an empty for loop) :

   ```
   for (int counter = 0; counter == maxnum; counter++);
                                                      ^
   ```
2. Change the stopping condition from `==` to `<` or `<=`, since the loop will never get executed if you initialize `counter` to `0` and terminate it when it's not equal to `maxnum` (assuming `maxnum` is not `0`).

   ```
   for (int counter = 0; counter == maxnum; counter++);
                                 ^
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't even notice I had that semicolon there. Everything works perfectly now and I thank you dearly.

Answer (score 0):

Following is working code you made two mistake one is after for loop ; and condition of for loop should be counter

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxMultiples{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Maximum Number: ");
    int maxnum = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Multiplier: ");
    int mult = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Displaying multiples of " + mult + ":");

    int current = 1;
    int result = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < maxnum; counter++)
    {
        result = mult * current;
        System.out.println(mult + " x " + current + " = " + result);
        current++;

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop as follows

```
 for (int counter = 1; counter <= maxnum; counter++)

    {

        result = mult * current;
        System.out.println(mult + " x " + current + " = " + result);
        current++;

    }
```

you are using ; at for (int counter = 1; counter <= maxnum; counter++); means you are terminating it at that point thats why it is executing only once